# Make python file accessible from anywhere by all users

Tags: python, access-control

I installed a program that requires you to execute a python script like this:

```
python fit_locus.py --help
```

I want to make the file acessible to all users without requiring them to navigate to the folder of the python file, so they can execute said command from their home folders.

I tried adding the install folder to the PATH variable and tried to create a symlink of the file in /bin and /usr/bin but it didn't work.

Is it possible to do so or should I require the users to navigate to the folder where the program is installed?

EDIT: Here's my PATH variable:

Without the export:

```
/gasgano/bin:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/bin/intel64:/usr/local/sbin:/‌​usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/esoreflex/bin:/‌​opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mpirt/bin/intel64
```

With the export:

```
/gasgano/bin:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/bin/intel64:/usr/local/sbin:/‌​usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/esoreflex/bin:/‌​opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mpirt/bin/intel64:/opt/big-macs-calibrate/
```

And the path `/opt/big-macs/calibrate/` is the one that contains the python script fit_locus.py

EDIT2:

On the installation instructions of the program I'm trying to make available to all users there's this little guide:

Set environmental variables:

1 - BIGMACS to the path of the installation directory

e.g.,

```
setenv BIGMACS /Users/ronald/big-macs-calibrate/ (tcsh shell)      
BIGMACS=/Users/ronald/big-macs-calibrate/ (bash shell)
export BIGMACS
```

2 - add installation directory to PYTHONPATH

e.g.,

```
setenv PYTHONPATH $BIGMACS:PYTHONPATH (tcsh shell)
PYTHONPATH=$BIGMACS:PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH
```

But it doesn't work either. The error I get when I try to run `python fit_locus.py --help`is:

```
python: can't open file 'fit_locus.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please post your `PATH` variable

Comment: Without the export: /gasgano/bin:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/bin/intel64:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/esoreflex/bin:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mpirt/bin/intel64

Comment: With the export: /gasgano/bin:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/bin/intel64:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/esoreflex/bin:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mpirt/bin/intel64:/opt/big-macs-calibrate/

Comment: /opt/big-macs/calibrate/ contains the python script fit_locus.py

Comment: Don't post it as comment, [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/281253/edit) here

Comment: Is `fit_locus.py` executable?

Comment: Should it be? I can execute python fit_locus.py --help on the folder where the file is with any user without a problem, I just don't want to have everyone navigate to that folder to execute this command

Answer (score 3):

To make something like this easily executable, add this as the first line of the python script:

`#! /usr/bin/python`

and the file itself should be executable; that is, the x bits must be set, `chmod +x fit_locus.py`.

Since the script is in the amended PATH, users can just enter the name.  For simplicity, you can remove the '.py' so users only need to type

`fit_locus --help`

unless there's a reason you want the users to be aware that it's a python script.

Comment: `!#/usr/bin/env python` can also be used, in case the python executable doesn't reside in /usr/bin

Comment: Neither worked out. I added the line you mentioned in the start of the script, used chmod +x, exported the PATH and tried to execute the file and it says "fit_locus: command not found"

Comment: Here's the output:

root@astrolab15:~# vim /opt/big-macs-calibrate/fit_locus.py 
root@astrolab15:~# chmod +x /opt/big-macs-calibrate/fit_locus.py 
root@astrolab15:~# export PATH=$PATH:/opt/big-macs-calibrate/
root@astrolab15:~# fit_locus --help
fit_locus: command not found

Comment: Ah!  I was unclear.  You have to remove the .py suffix by renaming the file, removing it from both the filename and what the user types.  Right now, the user should be able to type `fit_locus.py --help`, but after you `mv fit_locus.py fit_locus` then the shell will find it.

Comment: Still didn't work, same error as before (command not found)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way is to create a desktop launcher.  That could specify the exact path to the file.  The launcher could then be copied to each user's desktop.  Another approach is a smaller starter script to go into each user's home folder.  But then you have to use ./,  ~/, or $HOME/ before the script name to launch it.

However, you can add folders to either the head or tail end of $PATH for each user if you modify the .bashrc or the .profile for each user.  This is a permanent change that takes effect each time they log in.  So there are options.